# React Native : NativeModules.ReactToNative is returning null

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native-module

I am trying to access the ReactToNative method from NativeModules in React Native but its returning null. Also I have imported the NativeModules Library from react.

```
import {Linking, NativeModules} from 'react-native';

console.log(NativeModules.ReactToNative) // returns null
```

Anyone has any idea on it. From Native Modules I am tring to access NativeModules.ReactToNative.openURL.

The react-native version being used in 0.68.2

Thanks in Advance.